# Xilinx impact usb jtag 13.4 crashes in Fedora

Tags: fedora, xilinx

Hi I'm a novice with linux and Xilinx FPGA, but I'm trying to jump right in with both feet.

I'm trying to run Xilinx webpack on Fedora.  The problem that I'm having is when I  use iMPACT, and it tries to connect with the USB cable, iMPACT crash (shuts down with out an error message).  I'm pretty sure it happens when it tries to access the USB JTAG cable because this happens when I either try to initial JTAG or use the wizard to "automatically connect to cable and identify boundry scan chain".

I've tried installing the Xilinx USB drivers per their instructions, but that didn't help.
Does anyone else use iMPACT in Fedora?  I'm getting frustrated.

Don't know If this is the type of question that's appropriate for this forum, but I'm getting nowhere using anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- First see if your JTAG (USB) shows up in "lsusb" or "/sbin/lsusb"
- Then lets try to isolate whether this is a GUI problem or a fundamental driver problem

  - Type "xmd" on Linux prompt and open XMD
  - Type "fpga -f  to program the FPGA and see if this works.

If these two steps work it might be a Xilinx installation problem.